# SuiteScript add item at beforeLoad when creating a new sales order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, onbeforeunload, suitescript2.0

I want to add a line item at beforeLoad event. An item is added after the page is loaded. However, I don't think I can use the line item i just created. available quantity, onhand quantity, units, price level are not added automatically. Inventory Detail button is not there. Any advise?

```
  function beforeLoad(context) {

    var record = context.newRecord;
    record .insertLine({"sublistId": "item", "line": 0});
    record .setSublistValue({"sublistId": "item", "fieldId": "item", "value": 57, "line": 0});
    record .setSublistValue({"sublistId": "item", "fieldId": "quantity", "value": 1, "line": 0});

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try **CLIENT SCRIPT** - change to scriptContext.currentRecord.

```
if (scriptContext.mode == "create") {
     var record = *scriptContext.currentRecord;*
     record.selectNewLine({sublistId: "item" });
     record.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: "item", fieldId: "item", value: 57 });
     record.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: "item", fieldId: "quantity", value: 1});
     record.commitLine({sublistId:"item"});
 }
```

Comment: try within a client script, not a user event

Comment: On further thought, what you are trying to do is not really a "beforeLoad" action.. I believe the pageInit client script will work.